# Ns-3 Distributed Coordination Function and Collision Avoidance

Tags: udp, wifi, simulation, packet-capture, ns-3

I am new to NS-3 and I have a UDP WiFi simulation that works fine. I need to expand my simulation by enabling Distributed Coordination Function with Collision Avoidance. Can someone please explain to me exactly how I modify my code to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP over IP over wifi is already using the MAC-level CSMA-CA DCF. In short, your simulation is already simulating what you want.